# Different apperance of View elements on different API level-Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make my app on emulator API level 10 look the same as on API level 19.

[image]

`TextView` color, `Button` color and `ActionBar` overflow are different. Why?
I think that I can manage `ActionBar`, but `Button` and `TextView` remains mystery to me.

If necessary, I'll post xml & source files.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to make my app on emulator API LEVEL 10 look the same as on API LEVEL 19

Why? Users of API Level 10 devices will expect your app to look like other apps on their API Level 10 device. Those users probably have never seen an API Level 19 device in their life.

> TextView color,Button color and Action bar overflow are different.Why ?

The `EditText` and the `Button` look different because API Level 11-19 devices default to a "holographic widget theme" (e.g., `Theme.Holo`), rather than the legacy widget theme (e.g. `Theme`).

With regards to the overflow menu, if the device has a MENU button, and if that device is running Android 4.3 or older, the MENU button alone will bring up the overflow. Android 4.4+ devices will use the "..." drop-down for the overflow, as do devices that lack a MENU button.

Comment: Exactly. That's the same as asking win 98 to look like win 8, those were different times.